# Default XML and PHP filename

Tags: php, xml

I know that with CSS there isn't a default filename but main.css is commonly used in html it's index.html, but in PHP and XML what would you normally name your file if you were using it for a website?

Comment: Just index.php and something.xml

Comment: "I know that with CSS the default filename is main.css" — No it isn't.

Comment: "html it's index.html" — That's the traditional name for a directory index file.

Comment: "but in PHP and XML what would you normally name your file if you were using it for a website?" — "for a website" is too broad. It would depend on what I wanted to do with the program or data file.

Comment: Check with your web server settings, but the default file in any directory is usually some form of index. There are different priorities, but index.html and index.php usually take precedence over any other name.

Comment: you would normally name it in a convenient way

Comment: so you would probably use index.php for php and index.xml for xml?

Comment: I don't know that there's any default for xml. Web browsers usually aren't looking for an xml file, unless it's a bot looking for sitemap.xml.

Comment: oh ok so you would just use index.php

Comment: Only use `index.php` if you want to load it automatically when someone goes to the path of the directory (like with `index.html`). For everything else use a name according to the content. for example `login.php` for the login page.

Comment: can you put that in a answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no real default names.

You only use `index.html` for HTML pages if you want to load it automatically when someone goes to the path of the directory.

It's the same with PHP. If there's an `index.php` in a directory, it will be loaded by default.

For everything else choose a name that represents its contents.
If a PHP page contains the login I would call it `login.php`.
If I'd have several XMLs, I'd name the default file `default.xml`.

Simple as that!

Answer (score -1):

When you are using php or xml it will also contain the file name with .xml and .php doesn't matter it is used in website project or anywhere else but you have to name your file according to its functionality suppose if you have a file of php in which you are writing the logic database connectivity you can simply name it db_conect.php  .

Comment: Yes but what is the most commonly used filename such as for html index.html

Comment: index.html is your main file which will executed first its name is index because it contain the link of another file included in project. I hope it will  helpful for you.

Comment: i know what the commonly used html filename is I'm asking for the commonly used php filename

Comment: so if the php works for the whole website what do you call it (commonly)

Comment: It will same as you name the html files. like index.html it will be index.php .